# replace host url with requested url in php - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, url

i have a site example.com address that filtered , i use a park domain (example.ga) that from address (park domain) my site accessible

but i have a issue that; when user get a api request the result got in requested domain but some time my data is string and don't change address

**i want this** :(example.com is main address and example.ga is parked domain)

```
example.com/test/1.jpg ==> example.ga/test/1.jpg
```

when user request example.ga/data/, return data as example.ga

Comment: Do you own both domains? Also, do you want to replace `example.com` to `example.ga` before returning the results? Please try to make your question more clear for others to answer.

Comment: yes i want replace **example.com to example.ga** before returning the results, the urls are in array

Comment: Do you have an array of URLs and all those URLs have `example.com` in the values? And you want to replace `example.com` to `example.ga` in all the URLs of that array?

Comment: Also, what key has the URL in your multidimensional array of URLs?

Comment: @satish-saini
**item of my array :**
`{"title":"mytitle" , "url":"http://www.example.com/dl/2018/10/test.mp3"}`

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if that helps or comment there if you find anything not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through each element of your URLs array using [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function or `foreach` loop.

Here `$urls` is your input array.

### Using a `array_walk_recursive` function:

```
array_walk_recursive($urls, 'urlReplace');

function urlReplace(& $item, $key)
{
    if ($key == 'url') { // assuming url key has the URL in your multidimensional array.
        $item = str_replace("example.com", "example.ga", $item);
    }
}
```

and then do a `print_r($urls);` or `var_dump($urls);`

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}            ^example.com/test/.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$                    example.ga/test/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^data/.*                /$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but i want in php, because i want that for a few function not all site